# Change a parent element when Fancybox close based on user generated content within the iframe

Tags: jquery, iframe, modal-dialog, fancybox, fancybox-2

Sorry if its a duplicate but I've tried so many solutions here that I've lost the count...

**The goal:** when I close Fancybox I want to be able to change the class of the link that has initially triggered Fancybox based on the presence (*or not!*) of some contents inside the modal iframe.

Take note that these contents can be added or deleted on the fly by the user inside Fancybox while it's open and that the iframe itself comes from another dynamic page on the same domain/server. At the moment all I can do is to reach the Fancybox different frames but I can't get no content (*see the code below*).

Since it's a top secret project (*!!!*) I can't give you the exact code but the principle goes like this:

**HTML, *parent page***

```
...
<a href="#" class="fancybox-opener one">Click!</a>
<a href="#" class="fancybox-opener two">Click!</a>
...
```

**HTML, *modal page* (*iframe*)**

```
...
<a href="#" class="add-an-element">Click!</a>
<a href="#" class="delete-an-element">Click!</a>
...
<div>
    <div class="an-element">Can be here at loading... or not!</div>
</div>
...
```

**JQUERY *for the Fancybox***

```
$('.fancybox-opener').fancybox({
    ...
    type: 'iframe',
    beforeClose: function() {
        var triggerLink = $(this.element);
        var theElement = $('.fancybox-inner').contents().find('.an-element');
        if ($(theElement.length) > 0) {
            $(triggerLink).addClass('there_is_something');
        } else {
            $(triggerLink).removeClass('there_is_something');
        };
    }
});
```

Thanx in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simplified version of your "top secret" code that should do the trick :

```
$(".fancybox-opener").fancybox({
    type: "iframe",
    beforeClose: function () {
        var theElement = $(".an-element", $(".fancybox-iframe").contents());
        theElement.length > 0 ? this.element.addClass("there_is_something") : this.element.removeClass("there_is_something");
    }
});
```

See **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/rFny2/show/)**

**Notice** that I am using jsfiddle's option `show` in the URL, otherwise we will get "permission" error across the iframes

I also added a background color to the selector `.there_is_something` in the parent page to make it obvious when you add an element inside the iframe and close fancybox

```
.there_is_something {
    background-color: #ccc;
}
```

.. you should see `Lorem Ipsum` when `.an-element` is added inside the iframe.

Comment: Thanks @JFK for your effort but this doesn't work in my setup, I'll try later to make a «_fiddle_» to show what's happening but for now I don't have enough time for this. In the meantime I'll rely on the reload of the parent page even if it's far from perfect. «_I'll be back..._» ;-)